# Why does Python ignore LC_ALL?

Tags: python

```
[d33tah-pc][~] $ LC_ALL="pl_PL.UTF-8" date  
sob, 14 gru 2013, 00:26:48 CET
[d33tah-pc][~] $ LC_ALL="pl_PL.UTF-8" python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Nov 12 2013, 16:18:42) 
[GCC 4.8.2 20131017 (Red Hat 4.8.2-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import time
>>> time.strftime("%c")
'Sat Dec 14 00:26:57 2013'
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'pl_PL.UTF-8')
'pl_PL.UTF-8'
>>> time.strftime("%c")
'sob, 14 gru 2013, 00:27:09'
```

Why didn't Python use the system's environment variables in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it doesn't *ever* use them by default. You must *explicitly* enable locale support.

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, '')
```

Comment: +1. And it does this to act just like POSIX C code: you have to explicitly ask for the native environment with `""` to get the native environment. (I would link to the POSIX spec, but the server seems to be down at the moment… just google "POSIX locale" and it's the first link.)

Comment: JFYI: Here is the [source](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#background-details-hints-tips-and-caveats).